# How to parent a Ray Casted transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the `RaycastHit hitInfo;` variable, and I want the object hit by the ray cast to get parented by the main gameObject, which is the origin of the ray.

`hitInfo.collider.gameObject.name.parent = gameObject;` doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: `hitInfo.collider.gameObject.name.parent` makes no sense ... did you try `hitInfo.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Transform.parent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) `gameObject.transform.parent`.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'. I supose I have to get the GameObject out of the transform, so I tried `hitInfo.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject = gameObject;` , but i get the following error :Property or indexer 'Component.gameObject' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: do hitInfo.collider.gameObject.transform.parent= gameObject.transform;

Comment: @RaresRechesan you're welcome, remember to mark the answer as correct if it is.

Answer (score 0):

The parent is a `transform` object. If the raycast is successful do the following:

```
hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent = transform;
```

The gameObject that executed the ray will be the parent of the object hit with ray.